# Unable to check if queryset is a subset

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-queryset, django-1.7

I have three models

```
class Permission(models.Model):
    permission = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=False)

class PermissionMap(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=False)
    origin = models.ForeignKey(Origin)
    license  = models.ForeignKey(License)
    class Meta:
        unique_together = (("origin", "license"),)


class PermissionValidatorMap(models.Model):
    permission_map = models.ForeignKey(PermissionMap)
    permission = models.ForeignKey(Permission)
    validator_set = models.ManyToManyField(ValidatorMetaData)
    class Meta:
        unique_together = (("permission_map", "permission"),)
```

Now what I'm doing is getting origin, license, permission and a validators_list(which is a list) and filtering PermissionValidatorMap using them as such

```
map=PermissionValidatorMap.objects.filter(permission_map__origin=origin,\
    permission_map__license=license, permission__permission=permission)
```

Now I want to filter only those in which the validator_set is a subset or exact matching set of validators_list
For that I am doing something like this

```
map.filter(validator_set__in=validators_list)
```

But this doesn't seem to work, it seems to be checking for each element of the validators_list individually and hence returning duplicate results and 
returning even if the whole validator_set is not validator_list.

For illustration its behaving in somewhat this manner

[a->1,2] in [1,2,3] will give [a,a]

[a->1,2] in [2,3] will give [a]

In the first case it should've returned [a] and in the second nothing or empty
How do i do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is perfectly natural behaviour. Your query produces a `JOIN` on `ValidatorMetaData` and returns the `PermissionValidatorMap` for each pair of `(PermissionValidatorMap, ValidatorMetaData)` where `ValidatorMetaData` matches the query. Key here is that the `validator_set__in` lookup happens in the `ValidatorMetaData` table.

To get the desired behaviour, you'll have to exclude each `PermissionValidatorMap` which has a related `ValidatorMetaData` *not*  in `validator_list`, i.e.:

```
PermissionValidatorMap.objects.exclude(
    validator_set__in=ValidatorMetaData.objects.exclude(id__in=validator_list))
```